# How do I install PySide.jl in Julia

Tags: julia, pyside

I tried installing PySide but it says it's not found.

```
(Tibra.jl) pkg> add PySide.jl
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * PySide (not found in project, manifest or registry)


(Tibra.jl) pkg> add PySide
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * PySide (not found in project, manifest or registry)
```

Comment: That package never got registered and never got updated for newer versions of Julia.  Maybe some of it still works, but it would take some effort on your end.

Comment: You might be interested in [QML.jl](https://github.com/barche/QML.jl), which uses Qt5 QML, is much more updated, and well integrated with the rest of current Julia ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem like you. I think this package was discontinued.